# Explicitly mentioning Hash hint to joins

Tags: sql-server, join-hints

How do I know where to use Hash hint join explicitly? How does sometimes query optimizer gets tricked and applies a hint which sometimes affects performance?

Comment: "If you have to ask the price, you can't afford it"

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I've never used a join hint in. Ever.

They are only good for the data and statistics you have at that time. Where I have seen them used is to try and mask poor design or poor indexing or a poor query construct. A hash join isn't bad in itself

Can you update to show the query where you think you need a join hint please? And we can suggest other solutions...

Comment: I have noticed when doing projects using CDC statistics can become out of sync quickly and can be the difference between a nested loop join and a hash join.  In these cases the hash join, merge join or nested loop join is still ideal but SQL server doesn't know because stats are off.  Sometimes updating stats + the query is slower than the few instances where the hash join/ merge join/ nested loop join won't make sense especially when it is not doing a read ahead because it thinks the data set it is going to be extremely small because stats are slightly off.

Comment: I've see huge performance gains when using hash.  I only use it as a last resort when a query I know should run fast takes forever to finish.  My envrionment is different though.  I work in a 3rd party database that has no foreign-key relationships on any of their hundreds of tables.  I'm inclined to think SQL Server uses these relationships to come up with an optimal plan.  Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: @MikeTeeVee: er... not sure TBH. I'm sure I've read something but will try to find an authoritative source